# Visual Studio not showing Git commit options in context menu

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, bitbucket

I have an existing Bitbucket Git project and I have installed Visual Studio Tools for Git from [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c)

My visual studio didn't show any thing at all to signify I'd done this until I went into tools>options>source control and changed it from none to "Microsoft Git provider"

Now my solution explorer shows little padlocks and ticks in the right places but when I right-click there is nothing at all to do with commiting or anything to git

When I create a new project I don't have the option to create a new git repository either.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and have tried installing all updates and repairing the tool but still no joy.

Does anyone know what's happened?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am observing this on VS2015.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Nope! Just living with it and checking in via the folder.. taking too much time to look in to

Comment: I am seeing this even in v2019 must have been an old bug

Comment: The current missing feature affects the latest VS19 release 16.7.1. Being looked into: https://twitter.com/VisualStudio/status/1295357212731281408 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1152319/the-commit-solution-explorer-context-menu-option-h.html

Comment: VS2019 BUG. Workaround described here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1141222/vs-2019-cannot-find-the-commit-code-function-after.html?inRegister=true

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue, and I get the context menu in some directories and not others.  I was able to check-in using the technique below, but I also would like to get the context menu for "Commit" and "Add".

Try going to "Team Explorer" tab, then under "Project" click the "Changes" icon. 
[image]

That should list all the files you have added (highlighted in yellow below).  Enter a commit message then "Commit" or "Commit all".

Update: A few minutes later in Solution Explorer, I now see the Commit/Undo options. Seemed to be a delay before they appeared.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it works!

Any idea / clarification on the following:
- why does it disappear in the first place?
- why does it work via the "Changes" section and inserting a message? This actually commits and pushes the previous uncommitted changes.
- why and how does it suddenly reappear once one performed these steps?
-- Is it a visual bug Visual Studio encounters?
-- Are there problems with the local repository?
-- Something not right with the GitHub repository?

Thanks for anyone willing to provide some clarity!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: While yes @NealWalters that is correct the commit command is on the solution explorer even in 2019 but now seems to have been removed in last update.

Comment: that not the point @NealWalters this is ment to work from the solution menu has for years

Comment: This happened again in vs 2019 16.7.1, this answer resolved my commit issue. I was too dependant on the context menu option.

Comment: You can get there with the shortcut CTRL+0, G (that's zero)

Comment: Thank you, it fixed it for me in VS 2019. The first step is really what I was missing, everything else is as usual

Answer (score 4):

There's a shortcut to git "commit" on the Visual Studio status bar near the branch control. It shows you how many changes there are to commit too.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to clone your repository from GitHub in order to get the commit context options. I had this same issue and had to use the GitHub desktop app to commit changes or use Team Explorer is VS. I committed everything I had, deleted everything I had locally and then cloned it from GitHub. I now have the commit option available via the context menu.

EDIT:
I have also noticed that if you have the "Show all files" button selected in VS the commit context disappears. If you de-select show all files, you are able to access commit again.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue here. Sometimes it is displayed sometimes it is not. Now I am using TortoiseGit with TortoiseGitToolbar visual studio extension. It provides a great toolbar and also you can pull/commit changes outside the solution directory.

https://github.com/MRCollective/TortoiseGitToolbar

Comment: Same even in 2019

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the Team explorer tab and change your foundation server (by default it is one from microsoft) change it to git

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).